# Тестирование PostgreSQL в ASP.NET

Tags: postgresql, asp.net, asp.net-core

Добрый день. Мне необходимо протестировать некоторые методы проекта на ASP.NET Core, который выполняет стандартные CRUD операции. Проблема в том, что в тесте я создаю экземпляр контроллера и я не понимаю что указать в качестве IConfiguration как параметр, из-за чего у меня не происходит соединение с БД. Скажите, пожалуйста, что я могу сделать в данной ситуации и можно ли вообще протестировать соединение с БД на PostgreSQL?

Вот мой класс репозиторий

```
public class UserRepository : IRepository<Users>
    {
        private string connectionString;

        public UserRepository(IConfiguration configuration, string login, string password)
        {
            connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("DBInfo:ConnectionString");
            connectionString = connectionString.Replace("name", login);
            connectionString = connectionString.Replace("password", password);
        }

        internal IDbConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Users> FindAll()
        {
            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                return dbConnection.Query<Users>("SELECT * FROM users");
            }
        }
```

Вот класс контроллер

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserRepository uRepository;

        private string login;
        private string password;

        public AccountController aController;

        public UserController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            login = AuthorizeData.Login;
            password = AuthorizeData.Password;
            uRepository = new UserRepository(configuration, login, password);
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(uRepository.FindAll());
        }
```

И вот класс с тестом

```
public class UserControllerTest
    {
        private IConfiguration configuration;
        private string connectionString;

        [Fact]
        public async Task IndexUsers()
        {
            //Arrange
            var aCon = new AccountController();

            LoginModel model = new LoginModel
            {
                Login = "postgres",
                Password = "111"
            };

            aCon.Authorization(model);

            var uCon = new UserController(configuration);

            //Act
            var result = uCon.Index();

            //Assert
            var okResult = result.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>().Subject;
            var persons = okResult.Value.Should().BeAssignableTo<IEnumerable<Documents>>().Subject;

            persons.Count().Should().Be(7);
        }
    }
```

И вот ошибка, которую получаю

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[16.04.2018 9:33:44 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:03.0956025]         C:\Users\dima_kazin\Desktop\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Repository\UserRepository.cs(19,0): at WebApplication4.Repository.UserRepository..ctor(IConfiguration configuration, String login, String password)
[16.04.2018 9:33:44 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:03.0961583]         C:\Users\dima_kazin\Desktop\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\Controllers\UserController.cs(27,0): at WebApplication4.Controllers.UserController..ctor(IConfiguration configuration)
[16.04.2018 9:33:44 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:03.0966470]         C:\Users\dima_kazin\Desktop\WebApplication4\TestsApp\UserControllerTest.cs(34,0): at TestsApp.UserControllerTest.<IndexUsers>d__2.MoveNext()
[16.04.2018 9:33:44 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:03.0968966]         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Сразу скажу, что для коннекта к бд я через пользовательскую страницу передаю данные логина и пароля

ОБНОВЛЕНО:

Я добавил строку подключения в метод теста

```
[Fact]
        public async Task IndexUsers()
        {
            LoginModel model = new LoginModel
            {
                Login = "postgres",
                Password = "111"
            };

            var conf = new Mock<IConfiguration>();

            conf.Setup(c => c.GetValue<string>("DBInfo:ConnectionString")).Returns("User ID=postgres;Password=111;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Documents;Pooling=true;");

            var aCon = new AccountController(conf.Object);

            aCon.Authorization(model);

            var uCon = new UserController(conf.Object);

            //Act
            var result = uCon.Index();

            //Assert
            var okResult = result.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>().Subject;
            var persons = okResult.Value.Should().BeAssignableTo<IEnumerable<Documents>>().Subject;

            persons.Count().Should().Be(7);
        }
```

Но тест выдаёт ошибку:

```
 System.NotSupportedException : Invalid setup on an extension method: c => c.GetValue<String>("DBInfo:ConnectionString")
```

Что это может быть?

P.S. Может ли это быть из-за того, что тесты делаются в отдельном проекте по типу Библиотека классов?

Answer (score -1):

Я так понимаю, что вы пытаетесь покрыть функциональность юнит-тестами. Это значит, что тестируемые классы необходимо максимально изолировать, заменив зависимости на фейки - мок-объекты (Mock).

**Контроллеру** не нужен реальный репозиторий, ссылку на него необходимо заменить на интерфейс (`IRepository<User>` тот же самый), а в тесте - достаточно подсунуть мок.

А когда вы будете тестировать **имплементацию репозитория** - `UserRepository` (отдельно от контроллера, разумеется), то ему можно передавать конфигурацию для [In-memory базы данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#writing-tests) (это удобно тем, что не нужно пытаться отделить `DbContext` от DAL-кода), пересоздавая соединение и наполняя базу данными при каждом новом тесте.

PostgreSQL тестировать не нужно, это забота ее мейнтейнеров (=

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76114/discussion-on-answer-by-free-ze--postgresql--asp-net).